# Dash background/blur problem

Tags: unity-dash, 13.04

I have a problem with the dash's background in Raring, instead of blur it shows a greenish pattern. This happens with both active and static blur (installed Unity Tweak Tool to try these). No blur works well but it is confusing, it makes everything hard to read.

I have an onboard ATI Radeon Xpress X1250 graphics card. I haven't installed closed source drivers (none of them show up in the Additional Drivers section of System Settings).

The launcher and the panel also have this problem but only when the dash is open, otherwise they are fine.

Precise and Quantal work fine, I only face this problem in Raring.

Is there anything I can do to fix this other than revert to Precise?

[image: Dash Blur problem]

Comment: Hey, I am so sorry. There is a small bug in unity-tweak-tool that prevents you from actually changing the dash blur. This bug has been fixed in the version available from [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~freyja-dev/+archive/unity-tweak-tool-daily) though. Hope that helps with your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @jokerdino. I've reinstalled Ubuntu 13.04 and then installed unity-tweak-tool (version 0.0.5-0~135~raring1) just now from the PPA but I still get the same thing. I'm not sure if it actually switches to static blur. Here's a [screenshot](http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/1659/dashbluruttppa.png).

Comment: Guess it has less to do with dash blur and more to do with graphics card.

Comment: I installed CCSM and changed blur type that way too, but the problem persists. Only no blur works, but that makes the dash hard to read.

Comment: Well, I tried to install the AMD proprietary driver, both the beta and the main release and they both said my card isn't supported by them. I didn't have more luck with FGLRX from the repos either.

Comment: I've got the same patterned dash background in Ubuntu 13.04. I've also got the same onboard ATI Radeon Xpress X1250 graphics card. Certainly the problem seems with the card drivers. Any directions on what changed there from 12.10 to 13.04?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the X1250. Please see launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1167018

Answer (score 0):

Open up "system settings".
Go to "software $ updates"
Click on the "additional drivers" tab
Click nvidias proprietary driver instead of X.ORG s server
Reboot and you shouldn't run into your system crashing everytime you cick dash home

Comment: No additional drivers show up, I have tried that first. As I said this is an ATI Radeon Xpress X1250 graphics card, I downloaded the drivers from both USC and the AMD/ATI website, but the problem was not solved.

Answer (score 0):

this is not exactly a bug. Is because the graphic card, you see, many years ago the support was dropped, as you can see there are not private drivers and not even specific free drivers, as I supposed you had noticed there are always some graphics related problems. I tested raring and got the exact problem. This kind of problems persist on every OS, the best options are Kubuntu 12.04 and from windows, windows 7.

So far there are not solutions, which would be a new driver.

Maybe something like Mir will perform better, maybe not. Maybe there is a solution I but have had no luck so far.

Truth is there are many abandoned graphic cards and is a problem for many people.

Comment: Manck, thanks for your answer. I'm aware of the lack of support from the vendor but this card has functioned very well up to now on any Ubuntu release so I hope it will be fixed somehow. I'm still on Raring though, just turned the blur off and set a dark colour as the dash background. Thanks again for your input.